# Row Layout is layed out in columns

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

im new to angular flex layout and try to build some content with a selection list on the side and some content in the center.

This is how it should look:
[image: How it should look]

This is the code:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch" fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <div>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  </div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black" fxLayout="row">

    <!-- sidenav -->
    <div style="background-color: chartreuse">
      Sidenav
    </div>

    <!-- content -->
    <div style="background-color: chocolate">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is how it looks:
[image: How it looks]

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem ... i had the stuff in a module inside the project, and the module has no import of FlexLayoutModule. So after adding this .. flex is working pretty well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have non-matching tags, your code should work with one change of adding the fxFlex values to the child components so that they strech out the full width of the component.

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch" fxLayoutGap="10px">
<div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid black" 
     fxLayout="row">

  <!-- sidenav -->
  <div style="background-color: chartreuse" fxFlex="50%">
    Sidenav
  </div>

  <!-- content -->
  <div style="background-color: chocolate" fxFlex="50%">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

A stack blitz example can be found here: https://angular-flex-layout-seed-yok6td.stackblitz.io

Comment: nope does not work, even tried copying this one: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/apps/demo-app/src/app/layout/layout-fill/layout-fill.component.ts

Comment: @IEE1394 Is the stackblitz I linked working for you? If so, in your app are you getting any console errors? Is the flex layout module installed and setup correctly?

Comment: yes the stackblitz link worked fine, even the examples of flex-layout. i get no console errors and the flex layout module is installed correctly - hopefully .. i added it to my package json and my app.module.ts .. realy confused ...

Comment: even cleared the node_modules dir and reinstalled everything .. even not working... currently i use typescript 2.9.2 is this maybe an issue?

Comment: I tried installing and setting up flex layout. You need to make sure angular cdk is installed in addition to flex layout. Also import the flex layout module. If you still can't get the behavior you need, please post a working example of the project